# Fully support 2 languages in a Salesforce Community

Tags: community, napili, language

I am trying to configure a Salesforce community with the Napili Template. I want to support 2 languages also. I have successfully configured the second language, which is italian, like this [post](http://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2015/12/30/translate-your-community-builder-template/) suggests, through sitestudio.

The problem is that I am not verifying the correct layout, or at least the one that I was expecting as the perfect scenario, because, the only elements that do get translated correctly are elements like standard Salesforce buttons, or labels for components like Dashboards(*in italian, called Cruscotti Digitali*).

In the screenshot attached you find some elements squared in red, which I would like to have them translated, when I select the italian language. I see that when I drag and drop these elements, I don't get any option about my second language. I would appreciate any suggestion or workaroud in order to achieve the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To translate those elements you just need to go in the Builder. In the Builder you normally have the Globe icon to select the language. Then select the language and go to each component and change it with the translated label.

For the navigation menu it is quite similar you need to click on the element then on the tab name and change it.

When it is done for all elements just check it by previewing the page and switch from one language to another. Don't forget to repeat this for Article page, Topic page and so on

Comment: I am sorry but I can't seem to find the options that you described. Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to activate it via community builder > setting > language where you add them and publish. Going back to the builder you 'll be able to see the globe in the top right corner.
[image]